# I created a child theme and it doesn't work for some of the css files

Tags: functions, child-theme, wp-enqueue-style

I have a template with 4 css files: `rtl.css`, `style.css`, `main.css`, `bootstrap.css`.

`rtl.css` and `style.css` are located in my template root, for example: 
`my_template_root/style.css`.

`main.css` and `bootstrap.css` are located, for example:
 `my_template_root/assets/stylesheet/main.css`

`functions.php` code is:

```
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_theme_enqueue_styles' );
function my_theme_enqueue_styles() {
    wp_enqueue_style( 'parent-style', get_directory_directory_uri() . 'style.css' );
}
```

This `functions.php` code apply correctly only for `rtl.css` and `style.css` but my changes in `main.css` and `bootstrap.css` don't work anyway.

Answer (score 2):

You are calling your css files with wrong function like in following line of your code

```
wp_enqueue_style( 'parent-style', get_directory_directory_uri() . 'style.css' );
```

You are using `get_directory_directory_uri()` function to call files which is not event a function in wordpress.

Files must be called with one of the following two functions

1. **get_stylesheeet_directory_uri()** : This function will search files in your active theme's folder. By active theme means, theme that is activated by user from `dashboard -> appearace -> theme`. In your case child theme is active, so it will search file in your child theme folder.
2. **get_template_directory_uri()** : This function will search files in your parent theme's folder.

If your files are present in child theme's folder then add this code in `functions.php` to call your css files

```
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_theme_enqueue_styles' ); 
function my_theme_enqueue_styles() { 
    wp_enqueue_style( 'parent-style', get_stylesheet_uri() );   //It will call your style.css file
    wp_enqueue_style( 'style1', get_stylesheeet_directory_uri() . '/rtl.css' );
    wp_enqueue_style( 'style2', get_stylesheeet_directory_uri() . '/assets/stylesheet/main.css' ); 
    wp_enqueue_style( 'style3', get_stylesheeet_directory_uri() . '/assets/stylesheet/bootstrap.css' ); 
}
```

In the above code `parent-style`, `style1`,`style2`,`style1` are the user assign name and that name must be unique. 
And in one line only one file will be called, so if you wanna call 4 files then you have to specify path of all files in different lines.

**Note**: If your files are present in Parent theme's then you need to replace `get_stylesheeet_directory_uri` with `get_template_directory_uri` in above code.

For more detail read this [article](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/including-css-javascript/).

Answer (score -1):

Assuming that your css files are correctly uploaded to your server, the most likely cause for the changes not showing up, is that your browser caches the files. Reloading with ctrl-F5 might do the trick.

Another way to force the browser to reload all style sheets would be to attach a version number to it. The version is in the header of `style.css`. You can append it to all stylesheets like this:

```
$theme_data = wp_get_theme();
wp_enqueue_style('style1', get_template_directory_uri() . '/style1.css', '', $theme_data['version'], false);
wp_enqueue_style('style2', get_template_directory_uri() . '/style2.css', '', $theme_data['version'], false);
... and so on ...
```

Every time you change the version in `style.css` the browser will think all stylesheets have a new version and reload them